# What is the best way to migrate 18TB data in Oracle DB (on-premise) to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms

I have Oracle data base in On prem .

Total size of Data base is 18 TB .

Total no of tables is 200 but one table has 14 TB data and rest of all has 4 TB .

14 TB tables is like Audit logs table and it has very huge insert every day (very busy table)
I do have CLOB column in oracle table

I need to migrate my Data base to AWS/Aurora with CDC also .

What is best way to migrate with very little downtime .

This is what i have analyzed so far

1. I looked for DMS but this is going to take more than 15 Days specially 14 table
2. I have also thought to take orace back up and upload into S3 and then restore into Oracle and then do DMS to Aurora(but this very much costly and this also is going to take almost same time )
3. I did thought of creating flat file from Oracle and then upload into S3 and then from S3 using Sqoop to Mysql but this again same time and i did not much advantage .
4. I also looked at Snowball option but here also snowball will copy into S3 this also will take same time as or little less than normal upload with direct connect and from there i need to have oracle/Mysql using DMS only .

Is there any way to migrate this is at-least in week time correctly with or without DMS ?

Comment: How fast is your on-premises internet?

Comment: please check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/oracle-database/data-migration.html

Comment: @SamForbis is best in industry ..

Comment: Is 1 week the most important constraint? If so, you can look into AWS Direct Connect (https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/). It's not cheap but you will be able to transfer the data in time.

Comment: @dassum i have looked at that docs but as i have mentioned in point 2 i need oracle in aws and then from there i need to do DMS which is again time consuming minimum 1o days

Comment: @tankthinks i do have direct connect for my Organization but DMS is the bottleneck

Comment: As long as "best in industry" is over 1Gbps...

Comment: @SamForbis yes but main issue is DMS ..Max speed with best network that i have achieved is 1Tb in 16 hours and with that big table more than that because it has CLOB data as well

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to speed that up if AWS is having to convert your tables to its Aurora format... you're doing all you can it sounds like.

Comment: Ah. I missed the part where you want to migrate to Aurora. In that case, are you sure you want/need to migrate the _entire_ DB to Aurora? In this case, I would take the Hybrid approach: migrate the necessities and stream the rest over time as needed.